# How to delete photo from the Photo's Library of device through the application?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

I am getting the images from the photos library through `ALAssetsLibrary`.

I want to delete particular image from the photos library by performing select and delete operation from my application it self. **(Not from photos library)**

Using following code I am getting the images from the photos library :

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
{
    if(result != nil)
    {
        if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete it with use of `Photos Framework`:

```
+ (void)deleteAssets:(id<NSFastEnumeration>)assets
```

Documentation: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAssetChangeRequest/deleteAssets:)

Example app: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html)